# Is there a way to get notifications from OPC UA server, for subscription's sampling interval, even if there is no data change?

Tags: opc-ua

I understand with OPC UA subscription in client, we can get data based on publish intervals, sampling intervals and queue size.
But all these we see notification only when there is data change. But how can I create a subscription to get notification at every sampling interval, even if there is no data change?

Ex: Publish interval = 1000, sampling interval = 500, queue = 2.
And data value in the MonitoredItem changing every 2000ms.
Now I receive notification from server only when there is data change i.e. every 2000ms.
I need notifications every 500ms, even if there is no data change.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If your Publishing Interval is 1000ms you can’t expect to receive data change notifications faster than that, so for starters you will need to set that to 500ms instead.

Next you would have to create your MonitoredItems with a filter that uses `DataChangeTrigger.StatusValueTimestamp` and hope the server’s sampling implementation actually includes timestamp changes. I have found this to be server dependent, e.g. with the Siemens S7-1500 OPC UA server this will not work.

Comment: Should we set any deadband with StatusValueTimestamp trigger?

Comment: Not necessary unless you want a deadband applied. There is no deadband by default, so probably not.